# Unable to run Azure pipeline "A task is missing. The pipeline references a task called 'Cache'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am setting up my fork of a Github project with the azure_pipeline.yaml configuration.
This seems to work just fine for everyone else in the community but when I setup the pipeline it gives me the following exception:

```
A task is missing. The pipeline references a task called 'Cache'. This usually indicates the task isn't installed, and you may be able to install it from the Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com. (Task version 2, job 'compile_ci_build', step ''.)
A task is missing. The pipeline references a task called 'Cache'. This usually indicates the task isn't installed, and you may be able to install it from the Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com. (Task version 2, job 'test_ci_build', step ''.)
A task is missing. The pipeline references a task called 'Cache'. This usually indicates the task isn't installed, and you may be able to install it from the Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com. (Task version 2, job 'e2e_ci_build', step ''.)
```

Specifically,

- Here is my [Azure pipeline link](https://dev.azure.com/rongr/Flink/_build?definitionId=3&_a=summary)

  - I am creating Flink CI build pipeline according to [this instruction](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/%5Bpreview%5D+Azure+Pipelines#id-[preview]AzurePipelines-Tutorial:SettingupAzurePipelinesforaforkoftheFlinkrepository).
  - Which already have an [`azure-pipeline.yml`](https://github.com/walterddr/flink/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml#L40-L45) in the repo
  - It uses the template to run the job parameterized in [`tools/azure-pipelines/jobs-template.yml`](https://github.com/walterddr/flink/blob/master/tools/azure-pipelines/jobs-template.yml#L47-L61)

[UPDATE]

I modified the [jobs-templates.yml](https://github.com/walterddr/flink/commit/8e9f47647f005114786f08c13bce28449c035725) and commented out all steps with `Cache@2` and it [runs fine](https://dev.azure.com/rongr/Flink/_build/results?buildId=7&view=results).

Comment: This issue has also been reported here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/950320/cache-task-is-missing-yaml-pipeline.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to get this working eventually.

Apparently for my Azure account. I am not allow to use `Cache@2`.
changing all lines with

```
- task: Cache@2
```

to

```
- task: CacheBeta@1
```

resolves all my problem.

Answer (score 1):

By design, Azure DevOps does not automatically make all tasks available when you run a pipeline.

You have to add them manually as part of the pipeline.

'cache' is one such task.

I'm doing this in classic gui (non-yaml) mode as I find it easier to search for things
But what you do is in your pipeline add a new task and in the task search box type 'cache'.

This will bring up the task.
Click Add to include it in the pipeline.

For more information on this I would recommend reading:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems like I already have that in the azure-pipelines.yml: https://github.com/walterddr/flink/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml#L40-L45 not sure what was missing? btw i followed your instruction to use the GUI to add the Cache task, it seems to only modify the azure-pipeline.yml and made it weird :-)

Answer (score 0):

I do not see you added cache task in your pipeline from your git repo.

It should look like the example here:

```
variables:
  YARN_CACHE_FOLDER: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.yarn

steps:
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'yarn | "$(Agent.OS)" | yarn.lock'
    restoreKeys: |
       yarn | "$(Agent.OS)"
       yarn
    path: $(YARN_CACHE_FOLDER)
  displayName: Cache Yarn packages

- script: yarn --frozen-lockfile
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#example)

Comment: hmm that's exactly correct, because it is using a parameterized template and that's where the actual Cache task was. please see my updated description

Comment: I don't think that commenting out the `Cache@2` step is a good solution. The exact same build file is working here: https://dev.azure.com/aljoschakrettek/Flink/_build/results?buildId=59&view=results or here: https://dev.azure.com/georgeryan1322/Flink/_build/results?buildId=160&view=results
Why should it not work here: https://dev.azure.com/rongr/Flink/_build?definitionId=3&_a=summary

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I don't this resolves my problem. I think robert explains it pretty well. do you think there's some other issue there in my environment that I am not configuring correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error `A task is missing. The pipeline references a..` on one of azure task, `PublishCucumberReport@1` . I resolved it by visiting `https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/` and going to the task  and then clicking on `get free` button, which installs it on your pipeline